# Pip freeze for only project requirements

Tags: python, pip

When I run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` it seems to include all installed packages. This **appears** to be the documented behavior.

I have, however, done something wrong as this now includes things like Django in projects that have no business with Django.

How do I get requirements for just this project? or in the future how do I install a package with `pip` to be used for this project. I think I missed something about a `virtualenv`.

Comment: `pip` has no way to understand, that your project have no business with, say, Django. So generally you want to create an isolated virtual environment without access to system site-packages and run pip with `--isolated` flag to ignore stuff in `PYTHONPATH`. And of course you should not install packages into that environment other than required by your project

Comment: @Alik Alright, that's what I was afraid of. I'll look into creating the virtual environments later. If you want to submit this as an actual answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 151):

pipreqs can save the day for a specific project.
Just

```
pip install pipreqs
#then
pipreqs path/to/project
```

[Github Page](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs)

Comment: I might not be understanding this correctly, but doesn't this confuse install_requires and requirement.txt? requirement.txt are intended to be complete and exhaustive, where as install_requires are intended to be minimal. https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/

Comment: @Daniel Maksimovich, I think you mean to imply that the command will not output all the `desired - pinned` packages as should be in requirements.txt. This is true because the package `sniffs` the requirements based on imports in the files located in the target directory. But no it does not confuse the two. In any case, the `install requires`, will ensure that re-using the generated requirements.txt will install all requirements which may have been missed.

Comment: this produced a file with none of the packages that were in the python file, like `google-cloud-storage`

Answer (score 33):

I have tried both `pipreqs` and `pigar` and found `pigar` is better because it also generates information about where it is used, it also has more options.

Comment: Besides that, pipreqs gets mysql-connector and hydra wrong. Quite stupid bugs in my opinion.

Comment: Pipreqs is a little old and has some bugs.

Comment: Pigar works, but beware that simply calling `pigar` on the command line overwrites your requirements.txt file. There is no need to use `> requirements.txt`

Answer (score 21):

I use this command

EDIT: Thanks Addisson Klinke for suggestion

> <strike>pip freeze -r requirements.txt | grep -B100 "pip freeze" | grep -v "pip freeze"</strike>

```
pip freeze -r requirements.txt | sed '/freeze/,$ d'
```

When I ran `pip freeze -r requirements.txt` the output is something like

```
APScheduler==3.2.0
Eve==0.6.4
Eve-Elastic==0.3.8
## The following requirements were added by pip freeze:
arrow==0.8.0
Cerberus==0.9.2
```

I have a requirements file like this

```
APScheduler
Eve
Eve-Elastic
```

So I get this output and `sed` to remove the dependencies that I don`t want.

First output this to a file

```
pip freeze -q -r requirements.txt | sed '/freeze/,$ d' > requirements-froze.txt
```

That will output just the libs with version

```
APScheduler==3.2.0
Eve==0.6.4
Eve-Elastic==0.3.8
```

Then replace requirements file

```
mv requirements-froze.txt requirements.txt
```

Comment: I'll have to look into this, but I believe all the requirements were added by `pip freeze`, this would mean that the line being searched for would be the first.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the `pip freeze -r` option - didn't know that! I think the `grep` pipes are somewhat verbose/fragile though - a better approach is probably `pip freeze -r requirements.txt | sed '/freeze/,$ d`. That deletes the freeze line and all following lines to the end of the list

Comment: this breaks if you have something like `some-package[some-extra]` as the extra package is not included in the about after sed.

Comment: Can you give an example @TheFool ?

Comment: @LuisComS, my comment is pretty clear imo. It contains an example. Not sure if you are familar with that syntax. You can try with `flask[async]`, for example.  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/async-await/

Answer (score 13):

I still suggest using the official `pip freeze > requirements.txt` ([documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/)) compared to the two alternative features using [`pigar`](https://pypi.org/project/pigar/) and [`pipreqs`](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/) mentioned in the other answers because `pip freeze` lists the *effective package names*.

## Incomplete comparison among the three as per February 2022

| Criteria \ Tool | pip freeze > requirements.txt | pigar | pipreqs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name mismatch (1) | Package `my-package==1.0.0` | Module `my_package == 1.0.0` | Module `my_package==1.0.0` |
| Module overloading (2) | All packages `my-package1==1.0.0`, `my-package2==2.0.0` | None | Top-level module (version shows 0.0.0) `my==0.0.0` |
| Showing only directly used packages | No | Yes | Yes |
| Minimal contents | Yes | No | Yes |

(1) There can be a mismatch between module and package name such as `my-package` (package name) vs `my_package` (module name).

(2) There can be several packages using the same top level folder such as `my-package1` and `my-package2` (package names) which are installed under `my/package1` and `my/package2`, which are imported by Python's command `import my.package1` and `import my.package2`. Note that pipreqs notes version 0.0.0 for the not existing package `my`.

I know these are very particular cases but I hope giving people this overview can help understanding limitations and avoid possible mistakes.

Answer (score 8):

```
pip install pipreqs 
pipreqs>requirements.txt
```

That works easily

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified version based on the previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40026169/4052041

```
mv requirements.txt requirements.txt.bak
pip freeze -q -r requirements.txt.bak | awk '/.*pip freeze.*/  {exit} {print}' > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using linux then do it with **sed**

`pip freeze | sed 's/==.*$/''/' > requirements.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with `pip freeze`. In my case the problem was that I ran `pip freeze` without activating my projects virtual environment. I activated the virtual environment and `pip freeze > requirements.txt` worked fine.

So do make sure you activate your projects virtual environment by running `<virtualenv folder name>\Scipts\activate` on Windows or `source <virtualenv folder name>\bin\activate` on Linux.

If the `virtualenv` has global access you should run `pip freeze` with the `-l` or `--local` option, `pip freeze -l` which according to the [pip freeze docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/#cmdoption-l)

> **-l, --local** 
>  If in a virtualenv that has global access, do not output globally-installed packages.

Answer (score 1):

With your `virtualenv` activated, do `python -E -m pip freeze`. The `-E` flag means, according to `python --help`, *ignore PYTHON* environment variables (such as PYTHONPATH)*, so pip it's not going to access to global `site-packages`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package that works for me in windows and Lunix [Pipdeptree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/)
After the installation you can use Pipdeptree to generate requirements.txt file with just top-level packages.

Windows:

```
pipdeptree -f --warn silence | findstr  /r  "^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]" > requirements.txt
```

Lunix:

```
pipdeptree -f --warn silence | grep -E '^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+' > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, here's what I've found to solve the problem.

First create the venv in the directory of your project, then activate it.

For Linux/MacOS : `python3 -m venv ./venv` `source myvenv/bin/activate`

For Windows :  `python3 -m venv .\venv` `env\Scripts\activate.bat`

Now `pip freeze > requirements.txt` should only takes the library used in the project.

NB: If you have already begin your project you will have to reinstall all the library to have them in pip freeze.

Answer (score 0):

I do came across same situation. After activating the virtual enviroment and doing

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

still its collect all package install on my WSL ubuntu 22.04

After install **"pipreqs"** and typing  **pipreqs>requirments.txt** My Wsl got stuck.

The best solution is `pip3 freeze -l > requirments.txt` its only collected my local package used for my development.